# How to remove multiline space within cell value (in Table)?

Tags: tables, wrap

This refers to my following question.

[Setting single row height with multirow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97989/setting-single-row-height-with-multirow?lq=1)

```
\documentclass[11pt,table,a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, outer=1cm, inner=2.1cm,twoside,  headsep=26pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\nsr}{\rule[-1.3cm]{0pt}{2.2cm}} 
\newcommand{\dsr}{\rule[-3.5cm]{0pt}{4cm}} 
\small
{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}\begin{longtable}   {|p{2.7cm}|p{1.0cm}|p{2.4cm}|p{1.0cm}|p{1.3cm}|p{0.8cm}|} 
\hline 
\rowcolor{green} \textbf{ \textcolor{white}{ColA}} &\textbf{     \textcolor{white}{ColB}} &\textbf{ \textcolor{white}{ColC}}  &\textbf{    \textcolor{white}{ColD}} &\textbf{ \textcolor{white}{ColE}} &\textbf{ \textcolor{white}{ColF}} \\ 
\endfirsthead 
\rowcolor{green} \textbf{ \textcolor{white}{ColA}} &\textbf{  \textcolor{white}{ColB}} &\textbf{ \textcolor{white}{ColC}}  &\textbf{  \textcolor{white}{ColD}} &\textbf{ \textcolor{white}{ColE}} &\textbf{  \textcolor{white}{ColF}} \\  
\endhead 
\hline 
\rowcolor[RGB]{243,182,185} 
\dsr  Brainy Person  & \dsr  3.38&  \multirow{1}{*}{\parbox{2.5cm}  {\textcolor{black}{This is Very first line,~\\ 
~\\ 
This is Second line,~\\ 
~\\ 
This is IIIrd line,}}} 
&\dsr2.36 & \dsr 0.62 & \dsr 18 \\\cline{1-2} \cline{4-6}  
\hline 
\nsr  Kingestionisation Quesiton Queeneinsteen  & \nsr  1.46&  \multirow{3}  {*}{\parbox{2.5cm}{\textcolor{black}{This is First line~\\ 
~\\  
This is Second line,~\\ 
 ~\\ 
This is Third line~\\ 
~\\ 
This is Fourth line}}} 
 & \nsr 1.02 & \nsr 0.62 & \nsr  13 \\\cline{1-2} \cline{4-6} 
\nsr  Foolish Perosn  & \nsr  1.16 &   
& \nsr 0.81 & \nsr 0.62 & \nsr  45 \\\cline{1-2} \cline{4-6} 
\nsr  Attacking Person Rob & \nsr  1.02 &   
& \nsr 0.71 & \nsr 0.52 & \nsr  31 \\\cline{1-2} \cline{4-6} 
\hline 
\rowcolor{red} 
Datset 
& 24 
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Normal Value} 
& 23
& 342 \\ 
\hline 
\end{longtable}}
\end{document}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KtKX.png

In the above example, names in first column gets wrapped in one cell but every name (First, Second and Last name are far apart.i.e separated by multiline). How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the argument to `\multirow` is set ragged right.  However, you have packed the text inside a `\parbox`, which will try to spread the text to the given width.  Instead of using `\parbox` make use of the width argument of `\multirow`.  The syntax is

```
\multirow{nrows}{width}{text}
```

You have use `width=*` which says use the natural width of `text`, but put `text=\parbox{2.5cm}{....}`.  Instead you can write

```
\multirow{nrows}{2.5cm}{....}
```

This fixes the issues in your middle column.

In the first column, the problem is the rules you are adding, your commands `\nsr` or `\dsr`.  These occur in the first line of text in a paragraph, and so are adding depth to that line, pushing it away from the next line of the paragraph.  My guess is that you have placed these rules to help space out the table.  In your case it is only necessary to have them at one point in the row, so just add them to say the final column that will not have multiple lines.

If you wish to colour the rows then you need to put the `\multirow` in its bottom row and specify a negative `nrows`.  Additionally, since you rows are unusually high/deep you will have to add an adjustment:

```
\multirow{nrows}{width}[adjust]{test}
```

There will also be problems with colours of the rules.  You can use the `\hhline` suggestion from [Cellcolor overwrites partial horizontal lines (\cline)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65231/cellcolor-overwrites-partial-horizontal-lines-cline).

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[11pt,table,a5paper]{article}

\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, outer=1cm, inner=2.1cm, twoside, headsep=26pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\nsr}{\rule[-1.3cm]{0pt}{2.2cm}} 
\newcommand{\dsr}{\rule[-3.5cm]{0pt}{4cm}} 
{\small
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}
\begin{longtable}{|p{2.7cm}|p{1.0cm}|p{2.4cm}|p{1.0cm}|p{1.3cm}|p{0.8cm}|} 
  \hline 
  \rowcolor{green} \textbf{\textcolor{white}{ColA}} &\textbf{\textcolor{white}{ColB}} &\textbf{\textcolor{white}{ColC}}  &\textbf{\textcolor{white}{ColD}} &\textbf{\textcolor{white}{ColE}} &\textbf{\textcolor{white}{ColF}} \\ 
  \endhead 
  \hline 
  \rowcolor[RGB]{243,182,185} 
  Brainy Person  & 3.38&
  \multirow{1}{2.5cm}{\textcolor{black}{This is Very first line\\[2ex]
  This is Second line\\[2ex]
  This is IIIrd line}} 
  &2.36 & 0.62 & \dsr 18 \\
  \hline 
  Kingestionisation Quesiton Queeneinsteen  & 1.46&
  \multirow{3}{2.5cm}{\textcolor{black}{This is First line\\[2ex] 
  This is Second line\\[2ex]
  This is Third line\\[2ex]
  This is Fourth line}}
  & 1.02 & 0.62 & \nsr  13 \\\cline{1-2} \cline{4-6} 
  Foolish Person  & 1.16 &   
  & 0.81 & 0.62 & \nsr  45 \\\cline{1-2} \cline{4-6} 
  Attacking Person Rob & 1.02 &   
  & 0.71 & 0.52 & \nsr  31 \\\cline{1-2} \cline{4-6} 
  \hline 
  \rowcolor{red} 
  Datset 
  & 24 
  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Normal Value} 
  & 23
  & 342 \\ 
\hline 
\end{longtable}}

\end{document}
```

You should beware of extra spaces that were in the code for your headings (`\textbf{   Col}`), these were causing bad alignment.

If you want the first column ragged right, then you can start the table format specification with `{|>{\raggedright}p{2.7cm}...` instead of just `{p{2.7cm}...`.

If none of your cells are guaranteed to be single rows you could add a separate column to hold the rules.

[image: Sample colored output]

```
\documentclass[11pt,table,a5paper]{article}

\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, outer=1cm, inner=2.1cm, twoside, headsep=26pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\nsr}{\rule[-1.3cm]{0pt}{2.2cm}} 
\newcommand{\dsr}{\rule[-3.5cm]{0pt}{4cm}} 
{\small
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}
\setlength{\minrowclearance}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}
\begin{longtable}{|p{2.7cm}|p{1.0cm}|p{2.4cm}|p{1.0cm}|p{1.3cm}|p{0.8cm}|} 
  \hline 
  \rowcolor{green} \textbf{\textcolor{white}{ColA}} &\textbf{\textcolor{white}{ColB}} &\textbf{\textcolor{white}{ColC}}  &\textbf{\textcolor{white}{ColD}} &\textbf{\textcolor{white}{ColE}} &\textbf{\textcolor{white}{ColF}} \\ 
  \endhead 
  \hline 
  \rowcolor[RGB]{243,182,185} 
  Brainy Person  & 3.38&
  \multirow{1}{2.4cm}[-6pt]{\textcolor{black}{This is Very first line\\[2ex]
  This is Second line\\[2ex]
  This is IIIrd line}} 
  &2.36 & 0.62 & \dsr 18 \\
  \hline
  \rowcolor{teal}
  Kingestionisation Quesiton Queeneinsteen  & 1.46&
  & 1.02 & 0.62 & \nsr  13 \\
  \hhline{-->{\arrayrulecolor{teal}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|---}
  \rowcolor{teal}
  Foolish Person  & 1.16 &   
  & 0.81 & 0.62 & \nsr  45 \\
  \hhline{-->{\arrayrulecolor{teal}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|---}
  \rowcolor{teal}
  Attacking Person Rob & 1.02 &   
  \multirow{-3}{2.4cm}[80pt]{\textcolor{black}{This is First line\\[2ex] 
  This is Second line\\[2ex]
  This is Third line\\[2ex]
  This is Fourth line}}
  & 0.71 & 0.52 & \nsr  31 \\\cline{1-2} \cline{4-6} 
  \hline 
  \rowcolor{red} 
  Datset 
  & 24 
  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Normal Value} 
  & 23
  & 342 \\ 
\hline 
\end{longtable}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Still same issue.. "Kingestionisation" and "Quesiton Queene-
insteen" are seperated by multilines.

Comment: I see.  Answer updated.

Comment: Thanks it works fine but i have one more issue. When i used color  \rowcolor[RGB]{1,189,185} before each row only text in first row is visible but for others it is not visible. I have uploaded my code here http://textuploader.com/?p=6&id=MfckZ and corresponding output http://postimg.org/image/euojr5543/.

Comment: That is a separate question.  Essentially you should put the multirow in the final line, provide a negative argument and use the optional `fixup` arugement.  Then there is a problem colouring the rules.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65231/15925 for most of this.

Comment: Example implementing these things now added.

Comment: in your example you are using [-6pt] and [80pt]. How can it be known dynamically that i need to add this much points as my table is dynamic.

Comment: The `-6pt` should be the same in any one such cell.  The `80pt` is a linear function of the number of rows minus the height of the text you are inserting; this is because you have fixed the row heights.