# How to dynamically set the row height of a table based on another adjacent table?

Tags: tables

I have 2 tables side by side. Table 1 is dynamic and while table 2 is static (fixed content). I need to adjust the row height of table 2 which must be equal to total height of table 1 (like multirow) but I don't want to use multirow.

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{subcaption}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{minipage}{0.8\linewidth}

   \begin{tabular}{ | p{5cm} | p{1cm} | p{2.5cm} | }
   \hline
     A clear day with lots of sunshine.However, the strong breeze will bring down the temperatures & 2 & 3 \\[2cm]
    \hline
   A clear day with lots of sunshine. However, the strong breeze will bring down the temperatures & 5 & 6 \\[2cm]
   \hline
   A clear day with lots of sunshine. However, the strong breeze will bring down the temperatures & 8 & 9 \\[1cm]
   \hline
  \end{tabular}

 \end{minipage}
 \begin{minipage}{0.2\linewidth}


 \begin{tabular}{ |p{5cm}| }
 \hline
  For columns that will contain text whose length exceeds the column's  width, it is recommended that you use the p attribute and specify the desired  width of the column (although it may take some trial-and-error to get the result  you want). \\[5cm]
 \hline
 \end{tabular}
 \end{minipage}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

How can I implement this?

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to use \multirow?

Comment: I had lot of issues while using multirow specially formatting and coloring.

Comment: Related question.  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130907/how-do-i-create-6-parallel-texts-aligned-by-paragraph-with-3-texts-on-each-page/131394#131394.  In that answer, `\vphantoms` of the one table's row were inserted into the other table, and vice-versa.

Comment: @manish Just my personal opinion, but for what it looks you're trying to achieve, solving the few issues you might have with `\multirow` seem easier than trying to do without it...

Comment: @Xavier I am using multirow currently but row is dynamic and it is colored too. So i use /srr and use negative value of multirow but i need to add points to adjust the text in multibox. That is not good for dynamic table. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129518/how-to-remove-multiline-space-within-cell-value-in-table/129524#comment291818_129524

Answer (score 1):

To avoid `\multirow` you could simply use a `tabular` within another `tabular`.

I have also shortened the column widths to avoid `overfull \hbox`.

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{array}
 \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
 \usepackage{subcaption}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{table}\centering
 \begin{tabular}{|@{}c@{}|m{4cm}|}
    \hline
    \begin{tabular}{p{4cm} | p{1cm} | p{1.3cm}}
        A clear day with lots of sunshine. However, the strong breeze will bring down the temperatures & 2 & 3 \\
        \hline
        A clear day with lots of sunshine. However, the strong breeze will bring down the temperatures & 5 & 6 \\
        \hline
        A clear day with lots of sunshine. However, the strong breeze will bring down the temperatures & 8 & 9 \\
    \end{tabular}
    & 
    For columns that will contain text whose length exceeds the column's  width, it is recommended that you use the p attribute and specify the desired  width of the column (although it may take some trial-and-error to get the result  you want). \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]